# Will this combination of crankset work?

Tags: bottom-bracket

My frame specification for bottom bracket is BSA 68mm.

Would the following bottom bracket and crankset fit together?

1. cane creek eeWings Mountain ([link](https://canecreek.com/product/eewings/))
2. Chris king threadfit 30 bottom bracket ([link](https://chrisking.com/collections/bottom-brackets/products/bottom-bracket-threadfit-30))

The crankset is 30mm spindle and should work with the bottom bracket, but I am not sure the bottom bracket matches because it says it is for 73mm bracket shell. Perhaps with spacers?

Thank you!

Comment: Are there any internal obstructions inside the frame's bottom bracket shell?  Those could interfere with a 30 mm spindle.  Also, make sure any screw used to hold a cable guide to the bottom of the shell won't protrude too far into the shell.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, add a 2.5mm spacer on each side of the bottom bracket to convert a 68mm shell to 73mm. The spacers come with every Shimano mountain hollowtech bb and SRAM GXP bb for BSC thread so every bike shop should have a stack of them.

Easy!